# How to share an observable with a promise without two subscriptions

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable

I have an observable (happens to be in Angular) that I would like to get the value of between an Observable and a Promise. I need the promise version, as my service won't wait for the first emitted value to resolve in SSR.

```js
export class Numbers implements OnDestroy {

    private _num: Numbers | null;
    private _numObs: Observable<Numbers | null>;
    private _numSub!: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private ns: NumberService
    ) {
        // initialize as null
        this._num = null;

        // the shared observable
        this._numObs = this.ns.numbers$;

        // subscribe to the observable, save state
        this._numSub = this._numObs.subscribe(_num => {
            this._num = _num;
        });
    }

    async toPromise(): Promise<Numbers | null> {
        return await firstValueFrom(this._numObs);
    }

    get numbers(): Numbers | null {
        // get state
        return this._num;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._numSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

How can I share the Observable with my promise without subscribing to the observable again (like my current code does)? I am thinking I need to use either `share()` or `shareReplay()`?

Unless there is a way to wait for the first value to emit from observable without having two subscriptions?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Just use `share()`, like `this._numObs = this.ns.numbers$.pipe(share());`

Comment: Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73964539?devtoolsheight=75&file=index.ts) example.

Comment: Ok, so even if the promise comes in late, it will get the correct value?